# Extend angular 2 web app to nativescript app?

Tags: angular, nativescript

Is there a way to create native app (NativeScript) by using the code base of the existing angular 2 web app project ?

Comment: Been quite a bit of work on a nice seed https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced to provide reuse on all platforms (mobile, web, desktop). It is advanced so it might be a bit much for some

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the point. But you need to modify html templates. I suggest you start reading https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/ng-chapter-0